# Twitter API - Simple data required - Advice on how to get it

Tags: php, api, twitter

I require 2 bit of data from my twitter account to be dynamically requested.

(1) Followers (as of this month)
(2) Total followers

I have a couple of questions regarding how to get the data & if the data is available.

For (1), is this even available? or is this something I'd need to calculate?

For (2), so far I've been pointed in the direction of the Twitter API & oAuth. Now, to me - just get the total followers for my account - logging in via oAUth & using large class libraries (PHP) seems like total overkill.

How I can get the data I require?

Answer (score 0):

twitter has buttons you can simply drop on your page. this will allow you to show the follower count as well as allow people to follow you directly form whatever page you put it on.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button

Comment: Not quite - I need to get the current followers & I need to get the followers at the start of the month so I can calculate how much growth there has been at the current stage of the month.

Comment: you could look into twitter cards. i havent personally used them but here is a link to the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/cards/analytics and https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the data you want directly.

Twitter offers an API call which will tell you how many followers you have *right now* - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show

It does not provide historic data via the API - such as how many followers you had at a specific date.

You have two options.

1. Make that API call at the start of the month and save the result somewhere - then compare your current follower number.
2. Take a look at https://analytics.twitter.com/user/edent/home (substitute your own name for `edent`) - you'll see something like this for each month:
   [image]

There's no API for that data, but you might be able to screen scrape the data you want out of it.  Or just manually copy & paste.